# Breaker sending power to lights but 3 outlets wont work

Tags: receptacle

Our breaker flips often, and today the power shut our tv and window a/c off. I went to go flip the breaker but only the lights came on. I checked it again and again and still nothing. Only power to our lights. 3 out of 4 outlets in our living room are not working.

Comment: Where are you on this planet? Are all of these appliances on the same breaker/circuit?

Comment: If your breaker flips often, **stop overloading the circuit**.  There's more than a TV and a window A/C on that circuit!  Tell us what else is on it and we can help.

Comment: Is there a GFCI receptacle at one of these locations that isn't powering? These must be reset when the breaker trips.

Comment: WIndow A/C's should be run on dedicated circuits, not shared lines.

Comment: Modern window units of 5000 to 7000 or even 10,000 BTU/h can be run on circuits with other loads. Modern window units draw much less current than formerly.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit is overloaded, what you will probably find at the last working outlet or first non working outlet the back stabs have failed occasionally a broken wire or a wire nut but the failed backstab is quite common. Do AC units have to be on a dedicated circuit? It depends on the size of the AC and the circuit (15 or 20 amp). I would not put a TV on the same circuit as any electronic equipment because the compressor and blower motors create voltage spikes that can damage the tv , computers, audio equipment, I haven't had problems with lighting in the past but with LED's becoming more popular their driver circuitry can also be damaged I find drivers to be the failed component in most LED's I have repaired. Your issue came from overloading so it would be best to add a new branch circuit to power the AC unit.